# Find $k$ in $p(x) = 2x^3 - 6x^2 + kx -1$ such that its roots $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 = 6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let
$$p(x) = 2x^3 - 6x^2 + kx -1$$
and let $x_1, x_2$
and $x_3$ the $p(x)$ roots. What is the $k$ value such that
$$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 = 6$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Vieta's formulas and the proposed relation, one has that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} = 3\\\\
2x_{1}x_{2} + 2x_{1}x_{3} + 2x_{2}x_{3} = k\\\\
2x_{1}x_{2}x_{3} = 1\\\\
x^{2}_{1} + x^{2}_{2} + x^{2}_{3} = 6
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Consequently, we have that
\begin{align*}
3^{2} = (x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3})^{2} = x^{2}_{1} + x^{2}_{2} + x^{2}_{3} + 2x_{1}x_{2} + 2x_{1}x_{3} + 2x_{2}x_{3} = 6 + k \Rightarrow \boxed{k = 3}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Using [Newton’s identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities?wprov=sfti1),

$$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2= (x_1+x_2+x_3)^2- 2\sum x_ix_j=3^2-k=6$$

and therefore $k=3$.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange $2x^3 - 6x^2 + kx -1=0$ as $x(2x^2+k)=6x^2+1$, and square both sides to get the equation in $x^2$
$$x^6 +(k-9)x^4+(\frac{k^2}4-3)x^2-\frac14=0$$

Then

$$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2= 6= -(k-9)$$
which yields $k=3$.